# Database Class Model - Film

Tags: mysql, model

I'm currently designing a Film database. I currently have a film table with filmtitle, length etc. I then have a actors table. I have a junction table between these with filmid and actorid. This will have all the actors that play a role in the film.The junction table also has a role attribute.

Now, how would I go about showing the star actors in the film (2 or 3 select actors out of the however total in the film) Would I create a separate junction table of staractors with filmid and actorid, but this would be repeating the other already created junction table, or do it in the junction table, but this would mean there would be two actorID's?

[CrudeDrawing(forgot to include role in junction table)]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have built most of what is required already. Your junction table can be utilized to include a column for whether the actor is start or not (a Boolean column). You could instead use an int column where the values show how much of a star he/she is. You could also add other interesting information in the junction table such as character name, total appearance length, etc. There is no need for an extra table.

Examples:
One the left any number > 0 means a star. 1 means big star, 2 means small star, etc. On the right, 1 means a star. Note the two tables are not necessarily equivalent in this example.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way of doing it. Thanks for putting the effort into an example too.

Comment: No problem...Glad I was useful. For your information, if you are interested in  drawing a data model without having to buy software, you could use MS-Access if you have it or use the web. There are several tools on the web such as: https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/tour/ER_diagram_tool